# Adding thousand separator to various number types

Tags: c#, formatting, integer, floating-point, fixed-point

Am making a pure .net library with helper functions ([GitHub](https://github.com/billywatsy/Avo/blob/master/Avo/Avo/Extension_Number.cs)).

However I wanted to have a thousand separator for all number types and here is what I am currently doing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Avo
{
    public static class Extension_Number
    {
        #region ThousandSeparator
        public static string ToThousandSeparator(this decimal value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
        {
            if (numberOfDecimalPlaces < 0) numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
            return string.Format("{0:N" + numberOfDecimalPlaces + "}", value).ToString();
        }
        public static string ToThousandSeparator(this int value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
        {
            if (numberOfDecimalPlaces < 0) numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
            return string.Format("{0:N" + numberOfDecimalPlaces + "}", value).ToString();
        }
        public static string ToThousandSeparator(this double value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
        {
            if (numberOfDecimalPlaces < 0) numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
            return string.Format("{0:N" + numberOfDecimalPlaces + "}", value).ToString();
        }
        public static string ToThousandSeparator(this long value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
        {
            if (numberOfDecimalPlaces < 0) numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
            return string.Format("{0:N" + numberOfDecimalPlaces + "}", value).ToString();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

As you can see above ,

l have to repeat the same for 
int , decimal , long

l can achieve the results l want but is it best

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Avo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal tes = 294944.8484827M;
            int iint = 34;
            Console.WriteLine(tes.ToThousandSeparator(3));
            Console.WriteLine(iint.ToThousandSeparator(2)); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

but is there an eloquent way of doing it , but allowing number types only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no common base type for numeric types, unfortunately.

You could still reduce the repetitiveness of your code though, by encapsulating the common structure in a single function:

```
    private static string AddThousandsSeparator(Object numeric, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
    {
        // note this would crash when passed a non-numeric object.
        // that's why it's private, and it's the class's responsibility
        // to limit the entry points to this function to numeric types only
        return String.Format("{0:N" + Math.Max(0, numberOfDecimalPlaces) + "}", numeric);
    }

    public static string WithThousandsSeparator(this decimal value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
    {
        return AddThousandsSeparator(value, numberOfDecimalPlaces);
    }

    public static string WithThousandsSeparator(this int value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
    {
        return AddThousandsSeparator(value, numberOfDecimalPlaces);
    }

    public static string WithThousandsSeparator(this double value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
    {
        return AddThousandsSeparator(value, numberOfDecimalPlaces);
    }

    public static string WithThousandsSeparator(this long value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
    {
        return AddThousandsSeparator(value, numberOfDecimalPlaces);
    }
```

A few side remarks:

- There is no point in calling `ToString()` on the result of `String.Format`. `String.Format` already returns a `string`.
- `Math.Max` is a more concise alternative for the conditional reassignment. (For what it's worth, Kotlin provides readable extension functions as syntax sugar for this sort of thing, eg.  `someNumber.coerceAtLeast(0)` - trivially easy to reimplement them in C# for readability).
- I also corrected the naming slightly. It's "thousands" separator (plural), plus I think `With...` makes it clearer what the function does. The `ToSomething` phrase conventionally means a value is getting converted to Something, as if you were converting the number *to the thousands separator itself* - obviously nonsensical - rather than just adding it to the formatting.

Comment: making AddThousandsSeparator private is nice and the other types public , thus make change to a single function applies to all , thanks for that

Comment: Sure thing, happy to be of help

Comment: You can slightly _optimize_ it by making the `Object` parameter an `IFormattable`.

Comment: That's a valid remark (well, it's been a while since I coded in C# day to day), although instinctively I feel that the more specific the parameter type, the more of a false sense of type security it projects. It's a tradeoff of sorts.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely go with t3chb0t and replace `Object` with `IFormattable` in Konrads answer. Further you could provide default values to `numberOfDecimalPlaces` of your own choice and maybe the possibility to provide a `FormatProvider` which defaults to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`:

```
  public static class Extension_Number
  {
    private static string Format(this IFormattable value, int decimalPlaces, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null) => value.ToString($"N{Math.Max(0, decimalPlaces)}", formatProvider ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    public static string ToThousandSeparator(this decimal value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 2, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {
      return value.Format(numberOfDecimalPlaces, formatProvider);
    }
    public static string ToThousandSeparator(this int value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {
      return value.Format(numberOfDecimalPlaces, formatProvider);
    }
    public static string ToThousandSeparator(this double value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 6, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {
      return value.Format(numberOfDecimalPlaces, formatProvider);
    }
    public static string ToThousandSeparator(this long value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {
      return value.Format(numberOfDecimalPlaces, formatProvider);
    }
  }
```